# Callback .hover function isnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have this js function:

```
$('#linkNext').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        if ($('#conteudo .boxes').hasClass('ativo')) {
            $('#conteudo .boxes').removeClass('ativo');
            $('.boxAberto').animate({width: '0'}, 600, function () {
                // callback
                $('#linkNext').hover(function () {
                    this.iid = setInterval(function () {
                        if (cont > -565) {
                            cont -= 5;
                            $('#conteudo').attr('style', 'left:' + cont + 'px');
                            console.log(cont)
                        }
                        if (cont <= -565) {
                            $('#linkNext').hide();
                        }
                    }, 0);
                });
                $('#linkNext').mouseleave(function () {
                    this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
                });
                // callback ends
            });
        } else {
            this.iid = setInterval(function () {
                if (cont > -565) {
                    cont -= 5;
                    $('#conteudo').attr('style', 'left:' + cont + 'px');
                    console.log(cont)
                }
                if (cont <= -565) {
                    $('#linkNext').hide();
                }
            }, 0);
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
    }
});
```

On mouse hover, it checks if the element has the class `.ativo`. If it has, it'll remove the class and animate an element and beggings a callback. The callback isnt working, i think im using the `.hover` in the wrong way.

In `else` it'll begins a `setInterval` that is working great and so does the `mouseleave` function. The problem i have is only the callback, i dont know what im doing wrong

****EDIT*****

Now i changed the code, only using `.hover` with callback instead using `.on` with `mouseenter mouseleave`. But i still have the same problem. The callback above the line `// callback` isnt working..

```
$('#linkNext').hover(function () {
    if ($('#conteudo .boxes').hasClass('ativo')) {
        $('#conteudo .boxes').removeClass('ativo');
        $('.boxAberto').animate({width: '0'}, 600, function () {
            // callback
            if ($('#conteudo .boxes:not(.ativo)')) {
                $('#linkNext').hover(function () {
                    this.iid = setInterval(function () {
                        if (cont > -565) {
                            cont -= 5;
                            $('#conteudo').attr('style', 'left:' + cont + 'px');
                            console.log(cont)
                        }
                        if (cont <= -565) {
                            $('#linkNext').hide();
                        }
                    }, 0);
                }, function () {
                    this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        this.iid = setInterval(function () {
            if (cont > -565) {
                cont -= 5;
                $('#conteudo').attr('style', 'left:' + cont + 'px');
                console.log(cont)
            }
            if (cont <= -565) {
                $('#linkNext').hide();
            }
        }, 0);
    }
}, function () {
    this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
});
```

Comment: what version of jQuery are u using?

Comment: Why are you setting hover functions and mouseleave functions within the mouse enter function?

Comment: Because I'm a beginner programmer. I dont know if its the best way to do it but its working, only callback i dont know why isnt working..

Comment: You're rebinding that hover() function on every single mouseenter, and it does'nt go away on mouseleave, you just keep piling on ?

Comment: but if i dont use mouseleave, what should i use?

Comment: .hover accepts both the mouseenter and the mouseleave http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Now im using `.hover`. I edited the post but i got the same issue..

Comment: Did you check your HTML code ? Do you enter your condition ? .boxAberto hasn't 0px width ?

Comment: you can see the condition in line 6. in fact, if `.boxes` doenst have class `.ativo` it'll have `width:0`. its correct. the problem is the callback but i dont know what im doing wrong there..

Comment: It might help if you popped this in a JSFiddle: it's a little hard to tell how your HTML and CSS are interacting with this JS just by looking at the JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your following code:

```
if ($('#conteudo .boxes:not(.ativo)')) {
            $('#linkNext').hover(function () {
                this.iid = setInterval(function () {
```

for this one:

```
if ($('#conteudo .boxes:not(.ativo)').length) {
            var dees = this;
            $('#linkNext').hover(function () {
                dees.iid = setInterval(function () {
                ...
                ...
            , function () {
                dees.iid && clearInterval(dees.iid);
            });
```

Because when doing `this.iid` you were asigning a `iid` property to the function prototype of your callback, where what it seems you actually wanted to add it to your `.boxes` jquery element as your code implied.

So you have to capture `this` to a variable prior to enter your callback, I do with `var dees = this;`

Also when you want to check the existance of a jquery element, use the `.length` property.

Comment: it worked, but i have to leave the mouse of `#linkNext` and mouse over again to `setInterval` works.. how do i fix that?

Comment: you're calling setInterval with a zero parameter as interval duration, why?

Comment: in fact i need to know if the mouse still hover or something link that, i've tried `.is(':hover')` but it doesnt seem to work..

Comment: Add a class or property when the mouseenter, remove the property on mouseleave. This way you can check for that property or class anytime to know if mouse is over it.

Comment: i put it like a millisecond `setTimeout`, isnt it right? i chose 0 to it doenst stop looping while the mouse is hover the link

Comment: i defined cont above this code `var cont = 0;`, just noticed now i didnt put here but its in the code.. i'll try now to add a class, thank you very much!